# Should I store user data as claims or in a user profile table?

Tags: c#, .net, security, claims-based-identity, user-profile

I'm working on a public facing system which will ideally grow to a large amount of traffic. This is all c# .net work.

I'm using claims-based identity and so I'm currently using a user claims table to store the user data, but as the user base grows I feel this will become too slow to support the traffic. I'm thinking of possibly creating a user profile table to store non-security related data horizontally as opposed to vertically as in a claims table, leaving just the security data in the claims table.

Is this a reasonable approach to the problem? Can anybody share some insight from experience they've had with a scenario like this?

**Update**

My question isn't regarding the size of the `JWT` token that's passed around with the users' identity. My question is regarding the strict use of a "UserClaim" table to store **ALL** of the user's data in `Claim` form as opposed to having a `UserProfile` or similar table to store certain things, as well as finding that right balance of "this data goes into the claims table vs this data goes into the profile table".

Comment: Are you sure that the claims number/size is the problem? It would surprise me. In that case you could use the small session cookies solution of WIF. It uses a local store for the claims and just a pointer/key/reference in the session cookie.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to only keep data in the tokens that is used in authorization decisions and not bloat the token with user profile info.

Things like time-stamps between which the token is valid, the audience for which the token is intended, username, groups and roles for the user. See [here](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#rfc.section.4) for more info.

Keeping profile info in your token will force your application to get a new token if any of that info changes. Tokens are typically cached for their lifetime to prevent having to reissue them more often than needed.

Comment: Right but my question isn't so much related to the JWT itself as I can handle what claims are transferred via the scopes for the client. I'm just talking about user data like say "hometown" or pick anything off a facebook profile. I wonder if they have a profile table to store non-FK in a single record per user or if they have "hometown" added as an actual claim in a claims table. Or possibly both?

Comment: I have no idea how FB does it. I would think they have something like a user table holding all user-related info, but other info (roles for example) would come from a different table. In ADFS, you can select per claim which attribute to query from AD or what query to execute against SQL.